# En Conexion PhP y MySQLi por que no detecta si es menor que cero?

Tags: php, mysqli

tengo el siguiente Codigo Fuente en PhP el cual despues de hacer una resta la deja tal cual y no devuelve el resultado ingresado para que sea su valor original:

```
       <?php
    // Database configuration parameters
    include "../../includes/db_connect2.php";
    include "../../includes/db_connect_mysql.php";
    //Form Data
    $ip      = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $pw         = $_POST['pw'];
    $certa      = $_POST['certa'];
    $DP      = $_POST['DP'];
    $UserID  = $_POST['UserID'];
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
    {
        if (empty($_POST['UserID'])) {
            die('You didn\'t specify an Account Name!');
    }

                $cert = mssql_query ('SELECT * FROM PS_UserData.dbo.Users_Master 
                WHERE UserID = \'' . $certa . '\' and pw=\'' . $pw . '\' and status = 16
                and Verifi in (1,2,3)');
                //$active = mssql_fetch_array ($cert);
                if(mssql_num_rows($cert)==0)
                    die ('Disculpe o usted no es parte del Staff o La contraseña o Usuario No son Validos, Por Favor Intente de nuevo.');

        // Asigane UserID y UserUID
        $recar1 = mssql_query ('
        SELECT UserID, UserUID FROM PS_UserData.dbo.Users_Master 
        WHERE UserID = \'' . $UserID . '\'
        ');
        $active0 = mssql_fetch_array ($recar1);
            if(mssql_num_rows($recar1)==0)
                die ('El Usuario NO existe.');

    echo "<center>"; 
    print"Antes de ejecutar dicha consulta.";
    print" 
    <table border=1 cellpadding=5 cellspacing=0> 
    <CAPTION>Antes</CAPTION> 
    <tr> 
    <td WIDTH=180><font size=2 face=arial color=red><b>UserID</b></td> 
    <td WIDTH=180><font size=2 face=arial color=red><b>Puntos</b></td> 
    </tr> 
    </table>";          

        $recar2 = mssql_query ('
        SELECT UserID, UserUID FROM PS_UserData.dbo.Users_Master 
        WHERE UserID = \'' . $UserID . '\'
        ');
        $active1 = mssql_fetch_array ($recar2);

        $Antes = mysqli_query($conexion,'
        SELECT MAX(ID)
        ID,
        id_usuario,
        precio_final
        FROM sr_pedidos
        WHERE id_usuario = \''.$active1[1].'\'
        '); 
        $AntesR = mysqli_fetch_array ($Antes);              




    print" 
    <table border=1 cellpadding=5 cellspacing=0>
    <tr> 
    <td WIDTH=180><font size=2 face=arial>".$active1[0]."</td> 
    <td WIDTH=180><font size=2 face=arial>".$AntesR[2]."</td> 
    </tr> 
    </table>";

    //De aqui sacaremos el ID de pedidos
        $sacra = mysqli_query($conexion,'
        SELECT MAX(ID)
        ID,
        id_usuario,
        precio_final
        FROM sr_pedidos
        WHERE id_usuario = \''.$active0[1].'\'
        '); 
        $sacra1 = mysqli_fetch_array ($sacra);

    // Aqui resta los Puntos
            $scale_Record1 = mysqli_query($conexion,'
            UPDATE sr_pedidos
            SET precio_final = precio_final - '.$DP.'
            WHERE id_usuario = \''.$active0[1].'\'
            '); 
                    // Aqui NO VERIFICA si es menor que cero
                    $verifi1 = mysqli_query($conexion,'
                    SELECT
                    ID,
                    id_usuario,
                    precio_final
                    FROM sr_pedidos
                    WHERE id_usuario = \''.$active3[1].'\'
                    and
                    precio_final < 0
                    ORDER by ID ASC
                    LIMIT 1
                    '); 
                ERROR no verifica---->  IF (mysqli_fetch_array ($verifi1) > 0)
            {
   por lo tanto aqui no devuelve el resultado en caso que el numero sea negativo--->>>                      $devol = mysqli_query($conexion,'
                            UPDATE sr_pedidos
                            SET precio_final = precio_final + '.$DP.'
                            WHERE id_usuario = \''.$AntesR[1].'\'
                            // ');          
                            PRINT "Puntos devueltos por que sobre paso a negativo";
            }
            //}
            else
            {
            PRINT "Puntos Restados con exito";
            }
                        //}






    echo "<center>"; 
    print"Despues de ejecutada dicha consulta.";
    print" 
    <table border=1 cellpadding=5 cellspacing=0> 
    <CAPTION>Despues</CAPTION> 
    <tr> 
    <td WIDTH=180><font size=2 face=arial color=red><b>UserID</b></td> 
    <td WIDTH=180><font size=2 face=arial color=red><b>Puntos</b></td> 
    </tr> 
    </table>";          

        $recar3 = mssql_query ('
        SELECT UserID, UserUID FROM PS_UserData.dbo.Users_Master 
        WHERE UserID = \'' . $UserID . '\'
        ');
        $active2 = mssql_fetch_array ($recar3);

        $despues = mysqli_query($conexion,'
        SELECT MAX(ID)
        ID,
        id_usuario,
        precio_final
        FROM sr_pedidos
        WHERE id_usuario = \''.$active2[1].'\'
        '); 
        $despuesr = mysqli_fetch_array ($despues);              




    print" 
    <table border=1 cellpadding=5 cellspacing=0>
    <tr> 
    <td WIDTH=180><font size=2 face=arial>".$active2[0]."</td> 
    <td WIDTH=180><font size=2 face=arial>".$despuesr[2]."</td> 
    </tr> 
    </table>"; 
    }
    ?>
    <html>
        <head>
        <title>A.P. Deleation</title>
        </head>
        <font face="Trebuchet MS">
        <center><body><br /><br />
        <b>A.P. Deleation</b>
        <form action="<?php
    echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    ?>" method="POST">
        <table>
        <tr><td>Tu UserID de Staff:</td><td><input type="text" placeholder = "UserID o Usuario Staff" name="certa" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Tu Contraseña de Staff:</td><td><input type="password" type="text" placeholder = "Clave o Usuario Staff" name="pw" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>UserID:</td><td><input type="text" name="UserID"/></td></tr>
       <tr><td>Cantidad de AP que le restaras:</td><td><input type="text" name="DP"/></td></tr>
        </table>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" /></p>
        </form>
        </body></center>
        </html>
```

OK suponiendo que hago una resta en precio_final restando a un numero '1'
es decir este es 
Tabla actual

```
ID_Usuario precio_final 
255        1
```

UPDATE Table 
SET precio_final = precio_final - 10

```
ID_Usuario precio_final 
255        -9
```

Lo que no quiero es que si el numero pasa a negativo este se quede en la tabla y regrese su valor ORIGINAL quedando en caso del error que no verifica asi:

```
ID_Usuario precio_final 
255        1
```

LO que me esta pasando actualmente es que hago la resta y sigue restando en negativo NO DEVUELVE SU VALOR ORIGINAL.

Comment: Te faltaría hacer el `mysqli_fetch_array` de `$scale_Record1`

Comment: No amigo no me sale ya lo intente de varias maneras

Comment: ¿Y donde tienes declarada la variable $DP?

Comment: Tu variable $DP no tiene un valor, o no lo muestras en el código.

Comment: Si ya lo intentaste de varias maneras, deberías ponerlas en la pregunta. De lo contrario, la gente va a sugerir cosas que ya has intentado